# Wordpress has by default chosen a database and I can't install more than one wordpress in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2, mysql, wordpress

I'm a new wordpress user so this might seem you a very common problem but trust me I have searched what I'm capable of but couldn't find any answer.

So my problem is my I created a database for my first wordpress site 'testdb' for just testing how wordpress works and stuff like that, Worked with it and developed a whole site in it. But then I wanted to practice more so I extracted wordpress zip file one more time renaming it to word2. So instead of taking me to the wordpress installation page every browser of my pc is showing me this page:

[image: this page]

I thought I must have made a mistake then I made word3, word4 and many more directories and guess what everyone of them showing the same error.

I thought I have to delete the database and It will be fixed but when I deleted the database it showing me this page where it says error establishing database:

[image: this page]

I thought it is for only first site then I checked word2, word3 and so on and everyone was showing the same error.

Now I don't know what to do with it.

I guess I have to practice on one website and one database over and over again.

Comment: Did you create new Apache vhost configurations for each of these sites? Do you have an `.htaccess` file in `/var/www`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.
So what was the issue?? As I mentioned earlier I'm a new developer, Everytime I had to install new wordpress I always had to create a wp-config.php file. So I thought maybe I can just copy a file in `/var/www/html` folder so I don't have to manually perform it everytime. I didn't know that time that every wordpress site has a unique wp-config.php file in which all database connections and other stuff like that are configured. As soon as I deleted that file everything started working fine.